# Как снять ограничение на время исполнения ядер GPU?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, cuda, gpu

Хочу запустить параллельно несколько ядер с бесконечными циклами. Они запускаются, но циклы в них завершаются из-за ограничения времени исполнения ядер GPU.
Как снять ограничение на время исполнения ядер GPU?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что не надо снимать ограничения. Нужно перезапускать ядра, но подождем более сведущих людей...

Comment: Надо дробить задачу на мелкие задачи и их уже запускать. А бесконечный цикл на видеокарте... зачем?

Comment: Для моделирования деятельности биологического нейрона в реальном времени.